# Why are these Polymer routes not working when called from outside of the application?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using polymer starter kit 1.0.1 for a simple application. I have this in `routing.html`:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
   page('/users/:name', function (data) {
    app.route = 'user-info';
    app.params = data.params;
   });
   //other routes...
   page({
    hashbang: false
  });
  });
```

I also have an index.html file with this:

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
  <section data-route="user-info">
          <paper-material elevation="1">
            <h2 class="paper-font-display2">
            User:<span>{{params.name}}</span>
            </h2>
            <div>This is <span>{{params.name}}</span>'s section</div>
          </paper-material>
    </section>
</iron-pages>
```

When I have a link within the application pointing to this route like this:

```
<a href="/users/john"></a>
```

The page loads and the url in the address bar is `http://localhost:3000/users/john`. but when I enter the same address directly in the url and reload the page, I get

```
`Cannot GET /users/john`
```

How can avoid this error and have the same behavior as when the link is clicked within the application.

Comment: Add #!/  after localhost:3000 when entering url manually to browser. C what u get

Comment: @RobertRowntree that redirects back to the home page.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/#!/users/john   does what in browser location?

Comment: @RobertRowntree This redirects to the homepage and not the `user-info` route.

Comment: ./elements/routing.html  has docs in it if you want to drill down into "Page.js" for more details

Answer (score 0):

Because when you directly hit that path `localhost:3000/users/john` your index.html file will not be loaded... I can give you two nice options to solve that problem

1. use `hashbang: true` on page.js
2. use this element for routing, its still under development, but is pretty neat [easy-router](http://customelements.io/MartinsThiago/easy-router)